# ListView custom view binding errors when MahApps.Metro referenced

Tags: wpf, listview, mahapps.metro

Application I work on is WPF/.Net Core 3.1. It uses `ListView` with custom `View` (that show items in `WrapPanel`). Everything works fine until I add reference to MahApps.Metro and include necessary MahApps.Metro resources in `App`. Afterwards `ListView` functionality breaks up, items are not longer shown as in `WrapPanel`, just as ordinary list...
Also I get following errors in debug output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Columns' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ColumnHeaderContainerStyle' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'ColumnHeaderContainerStyle' (type 'Style')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ColumnHeaderTemplate' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'ColumnHeaderTemplate' (type 'DataTemplate')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector' (type 'DataTemplateSelector')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ColumnHeaderStringFormat' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderStringFormat; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'ColumnHeaderStringFormat' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'AllowsColumnReorder' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'AllowsColumnReorder' (type 'Boolean')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ColumnHeaderContextMenu' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'ColumnHeaderContextMenu' (type 'ContextMenu')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ColumnHeaderToolTip' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'ColumnHeaderToolTip' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Columns' property not found on 'object' ''TileView' (HashCode=8352109)'. BindingExpression:Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns; DataItem='ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target element is 'GridViewHeaderRowPresenter' (Name='PART_HeaderRowPresenter'); target property is 'Columns' (type 'GridViewColumnCollection')
```

Resources for the views are set in `Generic.xaml` file that is in subfolder `Themes`. I can not understand why it breaks and why those properties could not be found.
Here are also two examples. One is without MahApps.Metro reference. Another is with MahApps.Metro referenced and where `ListView` functionality breaks up.

Ok application, without MahApps.Metro and that shows proper `ListView` in `WrapPanel`, no errors:

**WpfApp11-Ok.7z**
[image: ListView with WrapPanel without MahApps.]

Application with MahApps.Metro and that shows broken `ListView`, errors and no more `WrapPanel`:

**WpfApp11-MahappsEnabled.7z**
[image: ListView with WrapPanel with MahApps.]

Here are both applications for reference:

https://filebin.net/qooty5o674obw29h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Binding Errors

The binding errors while debugging originate from the MahApps default style for `ListView`. As you can see in the [`MahApps.Styles.ListView` style](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/bbab412af829c9b565fdfdbfd7aeacd9a30805f3/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ListView.xaml#L96), the control template contains a `ScrollViewer`
that [references a style](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/bbab412af829c9b565fdfdbfd7aeacd9a30805f3/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ListView.xaml#L120) called [`MahApps.Styles.ScrollViewer.GridView`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/bbab412af829c9b565fdfdbfd7aeacd9a30805f3/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ListView.xaml#L5). This style is specific to a `GridView` and contains bindings to all the properties that are not found at runtime in the [`GridViewHeaderRowPresenter`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/bbab412af829c9b565fdfdbfd7aeacd9a30805f3/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ListView.xaml#L28).

In other words, the default style for `ListView` in MahApps expects a [`GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridview?view=net-5.0). In order to fix this, you will have to create a custom `MahApps.Styles.ListView` style to support your `TileView`.

### Wrap Panel

The `WrapPanel` is applied in your application, but not when using MahApps. It seems that actually a `VirtualizingStackPanel` is applied. The MahApps [default style for `ListBox`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/bbab412af829c9b565fdfdbfd7aeacd9a30805f3/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ListBox.xaml#L5) contains [this `Trigger`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/bbab412af829c9b565fdfdbfd7aeacd9a30805f3/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ListBox.xaml#L52):

```
<Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                        IsVirtualizing="True"
                                        IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                                        VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

It overrides your items panel (`WrapPanel`) that you set in your style which is based on this `ListBox` style. You can add this trigger to the style in your original application to produce the same result.

There are multiple options to solve this issue:

- Create a copy of the base style and remove or change the trigger.
- Create the same trigger in your style, but override the value with your items panel template
- Add a setter in your style that sets the `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` property to `False`.

Unfortunately these options do not work in the MahApps application. At the moment I cannot tell if it is related to other styles or the `GridView` issue above, but you can try if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This has gave me some insight into what could be an issue. Will try to follow your suggestions.